the word 'one' has literal meaning of '1' when it's used as an indefinite pronoun?


I’d like an ice cream. Are you having one, too?




I’d like an ice cream. Are you having it, too?


Q1. Can I say to the same effect of no.1 that "Are you having one ice cream, too?"(Does the 'one' in no.1 mean "1" in the '1,2,3,...100...'?
Q2. No.2 means "If I buy an ice cream, then will you have the ice cream that I bought and brought here?
I'd appreciate your insights in advance.

It' now duly edited.

Ice cream is delicious. Do you want some?
-- No thanks, I don't care for it. (I don't like ice cream)
-- No thanks, I don't care for any.  (Not now, thanks).
I'm having an ice cream.  Would you like one too?
-- Yes, please, but make mine a small.  I had one earlier today.

For non-natives, care for=like. Now it seems like 'care' is 'intransitive' functioning as a perfect meaning word like 'look' in the 'look at'. By the way, Does the 'one' in your "I had one earlier today." mean "only one ice cream or there is some possibility he or she ate two."?

one means 1 but the person could not be telling the whole truth. If he had more than one he also had one.

One here is a pronoun referring to something you have just mentioned. It saves you from repeating an ice cream.
(2) is not idiomatic. If anything, it suggests that the two of you will be sharing the ice cream that you are going to buy!

When you hear the sentence one, the 'one' sounds like '1(meaning only one)' but we can catch what it means because of context 'an ice cream'?

Of course one is pronounced the same whether it's a numeral or a pronoun! As I said, we use it to avoid repeating a noun that was mentioned in the previous sentence. (And you still haven't learned how to ask questions in English! "Does the 'one' sound like...?")

The sentence One often yearns for days past would mean essentially the same thing if the pronoun one were replaced with nearly everyone. This illustrates that the pronoun one need not be associated with the number 1 and mean some single person or thing.
